# If $F$ is an orthonormal basis ,we represent every $x \in X$ as a linear combination consists of finitely many terms ?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

If $F$ is an orthonormal basis in an inner product space $X$,can we represent every $x \in X$ as a linear combination consists of finitely many terms ?

in Erwin Kreyszig's book says no, but i dont understand why the answer is no. 
if $F$ was orthogonal or not, what could we say about this ? 
 Thank u for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the author refers to spaces of infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think to the space of odd, square-integrable functions over $(-\pi,\pi)$, equipped with the inner product:
$$ \langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx. $$
The sequence given by:
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx),\quad n\geq 1 $$
gives an orthonormal base, but if we consider any discontinuous function in our space, it cannot be written as a finite combination of the $f_n$s.

Answer (score 1):

An orthonormal basis (or Hilbert basis) in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ is not  a basis  in the algebraic sense. It is an algebraic basis of a subspace that is *dense* in $H$.